# Selecting data using jsonb data in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below table - assume tags column always have top level string keys:

```
name(TEXT) | tags(jsonb)
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------
teamA      | {"color": "green", "zone": "primary"}
teamB      | {"color": "green", "zone": "primary", "role": "user"}
teamC      | {"uid": "32-232-2dswdwsd", "availability": "condensed"}
```

Let's say I want to select rows containing keys color & role from `tags` column

I could do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE tags?'color' AND tags?'role';
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE tags->'color' IS NOT NULL 
  AND tags->'role' IS NOT NULL;
```

However the above query will become quite cumbersome as number of keys increase. Is there a better way to do the above query?

Comment: Use the `?&` operator:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html#:~:text=Do%20all%20of%20these%20array%20strings%20exist%20as%20top%2Dlevel%20keys%3F

Comment: Writing large queries as always cumbersome to do by hand.  What is particularly cumbersome here?  That `tags?` is written over and over again?  Something else?

Comment: @jjanes Yep pretty much, writing `tag?` over and over again becomes quite long

Comment: @MikeOrganek I will mark the question as answered. Can you post the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mike already commented, the [operator **`?&`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) makes that as short as possible:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl 
WHERE  tags ?& '{color,role}';
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

> Do all of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or array elements?

To only accept keys with non-null values (like in your 2nd example), add [`jsonb_strip_nulls()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   tbl 
WHERE  jsonb_strip_nulls(tags) ?& '{color,role}';
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

> Deletes all object fields that have null values from the given JSON value, recursively. Null values that are not object fields are untouched.

The latter cannot use a plain index, though. You'd need a matching expression index.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `jsonb_exists` function in postgreSQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE jsonb_exists(tags, '{color, role}');
```

Formal documentation is not on official [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) site, you can find it by running `\doS+` in the psql console.

**Note: It might not be supported your postgres version.**

Comment: This doesn't work in postgres15.

Comment: `jsonb_exists()` is the function used to implement the `jsonb` operator `?` internally. We would need `jsonb_exists_all()` for the use case, which implements the operator `?&`. But there is no good reason to prefer the function over the operator. Not least because indexes are bound to operators in Postgres, not functions. Hence the function isn't even documented.